# Why the specific symbols don't show up in my equations?

Tags: math-mode, equations, symbols

I was unable to get the equations with specific symbols to appear correctly.

The code is like this

```
\bm{\sigma}(t)=\bm{\sigma}^{vol}+\bm{\sigma}^{dev}(t)=K\text{tr}
({\bm{\varepsilon}})\bm{I}+2\int_{0}^{t}G(t-\tau)\dot{\bm{e}}(\tau)d\tau,
```

What I expected was to get a pdf like this
[image]

However, the pdf seems to hate me...

[image]

Could anybody help me resolve this issue?

---

Here I post the minimal part of the compiled text that works,

```
\documentclass[Journal,letterpaper]{ascelike-new}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}\usepackage{lmodern}\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[figurename=Fig.,labelfont=bf,labelsep=period]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,citecolor=red,linkcolor=black]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage[mathscr]{euscript}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lineno}
\linenumbers
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Needed to define custom headers/footers
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\bm{\sigma}(t) = \bm{\sigma}^{vol} + \bm{\sigma}^{dev}(t)  = K \text{tr} 
   ({\bm{\varepsilon}})\bm{I}+2\int_{0}^{t}G(t-\tau)\dot{\bm{e}}(\tau)d\tau,
\end{equation}
\end{document}`
```

Best,

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) As it currently is, your question can't really be answered, because we don't know what you're using that could lead to this behaviour. Can you please try to minimize the preamble of the document this occurs in by commenting out every line that doesn't cause this issue (bisectioning should be a good approach to find the lines at fault reasonably fast)?

Comment: My guess is that you're loading conflicting font packages. Please, add your document preamble and we can diagnose the issue.

Comment: Sorry, I just get a chance to update the description. This could be the simplest code block I could create. The issue stays there.

Comment: you specify multiple fonts ( `lmodern` font and `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` ). i am not an expert, but try to remove the last two and see what you get.

Comment: Wow, thanks, you are definitely an expert. I was suggested to include some of these packages to resolve some issues but I didn't expect it could induce such a problem. Thanks again!

Comment: I have another problem. This original template from ASCE journal include these two packages. I'm wondering if other people met the similar issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The offending packages seem to be the combination of `mathptmx` and `newtxmath` here (or more generally loading another font after `newtxmath`). As Yorgos already mentioned you load quite a few competing font packages and you might want to simplify things by removing the ones you don't really need (for example `newtxmath` and `newtxtext` would overwrite most of `lmodern`'s effects). The following slimmed down preamble should work (I also removed some packages which were loaded twice):

```
\documentclass[Journal,letterpaper]{ascelike-new}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{lmodern} % removed in favour of newtxtext and newtxmath
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[figurename=Fig.,labelfont=bf,labelsep=period]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
%\usepackage{mathptmx} % removed because it causes your issue in combination
                       % with newtxmath
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage[mathscr]{euscript}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lineno}
\linenumbers
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Needed to define custom headers/footers
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,citecolor=red,linkcolor=black]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\bm{\sigma}(t) = \bm{\sigma}^{vol} + \bm{\sigma}^{dev}(t)  = K \text{tr} 
   ({\bm{\varepsilon}})\bm{I}+2\int_{0}^{t}G(t-\tau)\dot{\bm{e}}(\tau)d\tau,
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried what you suggested but it doesn't work. But if I comment newtxtext and newtxmath, It works well. so I'm confused ....

Comment: @egreg points that the problem was font-related. i made the (almost) right guessing on the fonts :)

Comment: @RilinShen this might be the case because the class does load other fonts, too. I don't have access to this class, so I tested with `article`. Sorry for the inconvenience. If `newtxmath` doesn't work with that class, you should remove it in favour of the other packages, of course.

Comment: @Yorgos loading `lmodern` after `newtxmath` leads to the same problems. So your guess was correct :)

Comment: @Skillmon@Yorgos, Thanks, it helps me a lot.